# NodeJS Server to NodeJS Client notification

Tags: node.js, notifications

I've the following situation.

I have a **hosted node server** application in Amazon, and I have **node clients** in our users, which serves in their internally network, so this is a server/client node app.

The situation is, my hosted node, must send notifications to our node clients, and this node clients does not necessary have a valid internet IP and I can't access them directly.

My hosted node have to notify its clients just a few times a day in random times, and this will not occurs all days, **BUT** when some condition is achieved in that server, the clients must be notified.

So my options until now are:

- My node clients send a request from time to time to check that specific condition, which is a dummy way to do that;
- I can use websockets, and it works, but websockets keep the connection open to all my clients.

This two options does not appears to fit my requirements.

There is some functionality that works like push notifications, where my node server sends a notification to my node client? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with keeping the connection open?

Comment: It is not a resource consuming? Or have security issues due to it? I've no previous experience with websockets...

Comment: Sure, everything consumes resources.  That doesn't make it a problem.  You're talking about an insignificantly small amount of memory here.  Also, you don't need web sockets unless you're doing bidirectional communication between a web browser and a server.  A normal network socket will do.  And no, there isn't any security issue with keeping a connection open for a long time.

Comment: Well, I really don't need bidirectional comunication, just from server to client, thats why I was thinking in something like push notifications, but I can't see how my server can open a normal socket for my clients, is that possible? Thanks for your help Brad.

Comment: How could you push something to a device that you can't connect to?  (You can't.)  Your client must connect out to something, whether it be some sort of push notification service, or your server directly.  You might as well use your server directly.  If these were all on the same network, you could use multicast, but they're not.

Comment: And yes, it's possible to open a normal network socket.  I wouldn't have suggested you do that unless it wasn't.  Go read the Node.js documentation.  https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but yes, I know that is possible to open sockets connections with node, my doubt was more about how my server reach my client. Any way, I will use SSE instead, is the best fit for my problem and I dont have to implement all manually as you suggest. Futhermore as I've seen, keep connections opend is not a problem.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you do it all manually... just pointing out that you don't need web sockets.  SSE is a good choice depending on your data, but note that you must use text data with it.  You can't send binary data via SSE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is **SSE**, or Server Sent Events. Check out this article on [Medium](https://medium.com/conectric-networks/a-look-at-server-sent-events-54a77f8d6ff7) for a simple explanation and sample implementation.

Caveat: I believe the client connection must remain open, however, it's likely more appropriate than WebSockets, if all you need is unidirectional communication.

Comment: If the solution cannot be client polling than clients behind address translation need to be connected permanently in order to be able to be reachable at any given time.  Also depending on the situation it is important to use standard protocols and ports as things need to get through client firewalls

Comment: @jcuypers, you are rigth, we have to hold the conection between them to achieve "server send" behavior, even if only unidirectional comunication is needed, in my case, I think SSE is the best fit, thanks you all for your help!

Comment: well, might I propose still to look into SNS.  I kind of forgot about it.  you could circumvent the "connected" part with it.  since all machines connect to amazon SNS. and there's a hold queue for notification sent. so you can chose the connect interval for every machine... even if connections are down are whatever they will get the message whenever.  different queues for different purposes. all kind or protocols HTTP(S), mails, sms, MQ. etc. 1M messages are free per month. and the best things is ... its all ready. just need API calls.  im not a sales guy but this is a black box ready to go

Comment: bcs the length was limited:  according to me the connectivity is not even the problem.  you need to be able to maintain the state of all messages for every client. which client is connected, which not, which has received which and which need to be resent.   this is the most involved part for me with SSE and will take long to get right. If at all

Comment: Humm, SNS appears to be a great tool, but we have no certain if we will use AWS ahead, it is not my decision, but thanks man, you really had helped.

Answer (score 1):

**socket.io** easy to setup and maintain, keep alive support easy through firewalls and address translation. Scalable etc. Well suported. Who cares about open connections.just keepalive.  As you are already on amazon there is an option called  **amazon SNS**. Type of push service for bulk or group based etc notifications. Check if it fits your requirements.  I think it would fit perfectly your needs and is very flexible.